# Execute a program with a parameter from a *.bat file

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, windows-7, cmd

I would like your help with an issue.
I have a VB application located into a foler:

> C:\folder\program.exe

I need to execute it using a *.bat file, but I also need to send a parameter like this:

> `CompRate&--&C:\folder\subfolder\CompRate&--&False&--&`

When I execute the application using the IDE (VS2010) it goes to a **Case** statement (in this case '**CompRate**') and generates a file with the same name into the folder 'C:\folder\subfolder\'

I have tried in the bat file this:

> "C:\folder\program.exe" "CompRate&--&C:\folder\subfolder\CompRate&--&False&--&"

this

> "C:\folder\program.exe" CompRate&--&C:\folder\subfolder\CompRate&--&False&--&

and other options.

Comment: Escape ampersands with `^`

Comment: @Noodles You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape ampersands with ^

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.


.
--
```